# Why JVM (Android Studio or IntelliJ) doesn't start/work with decimal heap memory (such as -Xmx2.5g)?

Tags: android-studio, jvm

I was changing heap memory values on Android Studio and found when heap memory was set to fractional values, such as -Xmx2.5g, it didn't start and produced launch error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKsuQ.jpg)

But if heap memory was set as -Xmx2560m, Android Studio at launch time produced no error. I guess it could be due to fractional value. I have googled reason but couldn't find any reason.

**Why setting decimal heap values in JVM is invalid?**

Comment: Because it was never specified that using decimal values for this option was valid. Likewise, neither, `-Xmx2½g` nor `-XmxFreekinLarge`, are valid options.

Comment: @apangin and Holger Any of you can post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM accepts only integer values for memory size arguments.
[Here is the function](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a9b412abe617/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l575) that parses size strings.